# Departments of an Uplifted Galactic Government

Tags: space, government, civilization

One of the gods in the universe stumbled across an species with potential and decided to uplift it. Instead of uplifting over the course of a couple thousand years, the god decided to do it in one year. A couple million individuals were plucked from their lives and mentally and physically enhanced using divine powers. The god taught them how the universe works and other fundamental concepts in the STEM(Science, Technology, Engineering and Mathematics) fields and military science. The god explained that they were not alone in the universe and the uplifted species will eventually encounter another space civilization. Satisfied with its work, the god moved on, leaving the newly founded civilization with a single goal, explore the galaxy.

While this civilization is forming a government, they decided to have a single executive and a group of department heads who also act as advisors.

What kind of departments would be formed/ required to maintain a science driven, militaristic space civilization?

So far, I have a department of planetary administration, Technology, space fleet, army, air force, navy and external affairs.

Edit : The species was at max tribal when they got uplifted and the god has a secret agenda for purposely making the civilization militaristic.

Comment: I would recommend a department for waste management. You might not think its important until you realize all that shit has to go somewhere. On a more serious side, why not mimic the setup any real government has?

Comment: All those military departments seem unnecessary. Once you have advanced enough space warfare, ground/air/sea troops become dependant on your space fleets. You may want to have a single military dep, collapsing those others as single facets of the same institution. Either that or split between defense (military) and security (policing) deparments.

Comment: The gods taught them everything about STEM and military, but not about civics and humanities? These species are in for a rough ride and a lot of experimentation with their government structure.

Comment: @Shadowzee I always forget about waste management aspect! Also, i figure that an uplifed civilization would be different from conventional governments.

Comment: @Liquid fair point. It could be consolidated into one branch.

Comment: @Alexander the god wants to see the uplifted deal with it. Perhaps it too is from a science driven society?

Comment: @Vernian42 I think it would be different, but not in terms of the duties that the government would need to fulfill. People still have basic needs and requirements. Instead, they might be far more unified in their ideology and pursuit of technology and exploration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While this civilization is forming a government, they decided to have a single executive and a group of department heads who also act as advisors.
>
> What kind of departments would be formed/ required to maintain a science driven, militaristic space civilization?

By sheer luck, I have here a document that answers this very same question.
Welcome to

## Liquid 101 guide to make your galactic civilization more interesting than Space Nazis

Everybody loves a good, all-conquering, militaristic while science-loving space civilization. But what kind of deparments would you need to make it work? What kind of people do you want as advisors for your single <strike>dictator</strike> chief?
Here's my selection. In some departments, I have proposed smaller sub-section called branches; each branch oversees a particular area of interest. The idea behind branches is to minimize the total number of departments, improve cooperation, and expand each deparments core concepts.

### Defense

*As part of an expansionist, militaristic society you'll be probably attacking, but it's generally better to keep appearances*

This department will be in charge of the military. The suggested branches are:

- **Space Forces**, for all your 0 gravity needs,
- **Planetary Forces**, aka when things get down to earth,
- **Logistics**, possibly the tiresome job of keeping them all together.

Of course, they are supposed to work closely with each other. Space forces will train its own personell for manning the fleets, but ground troops from Planetary are expected to be on board too - mainly to get from mission A to mission B. Needless to say, the Logistic branch is vital to every operation, while being the less gun-populated one. It's expected to work closely with the science and exploration departments.

### Administration

*Aka the mind-numbing tasks nobody wants to do*

Your administration department should ensure that everything in your empire runs as intended in the daily lives of your fellow citizens. I'll point out some area of interests:

- **Security**: Law enforcement, internal security, and policing. While this could do jointly with your army, it's usually better to keep police under a different power structure.
- **Public Services**: Not to be mistaken with the public toilets. Public Services should manage everything from waste disposal to healthcare, with welfare in between.
- **Rules and Regulations**: a branch tasked with ensuring that the law code is followed and in good health. This branch could have judiciary power - running tribunals - and a light legislative power - as it could suggest new laws or law edits to your chief.

### Exploration and Commerce

*There's money to be made in space!*

The best suited department for navigators, explorers and merchants.

- **Trade** would be the branch tasked with estabilishing routes, deals, both internal to your civilization and external (toward other uplift or not uplift species).
- the **Scouting** branch would tasking with exploring the vast nothingness of space, both with manned missions, space probes, and telescopes.
- **Colonization** would be responsible for setting and mantaining new colonies, and make sure they succeed.

The emphasis here is knowing what's out there, putting foot on it, make it profitable, rinse and repeat. The goal of your civilization is to expand, so it makes sense having some of your staff getting really specialized at that. Of course, a close cooperation with the science department for all the technology needs is to be expected.

## Science

*Putting it all together*

Well, what can I say about science? It would cover a lot of topics, to be sure; and unless your uplifted society has discovery a *theory of everything*, you will be probably stuck with all the various fields of scientific knowledge banded together. It would make sense to have different branches for , lets say, **Medicine**, **Physics**, **Computer science**, **Biology** and so on. This would also give your scientist a very familiar academic feel. If you'd like to be more general, you could distinguish a branch for **Academic** and **Applied** sciences, and maybe a branch devoted to **Research and Development** projects.

### Culture

*Wait, do I even need this?*

Short answer, yes, you do. Even in a militaristic, science based society you still need to cultivate your culture - exspecially when your people, recently uplifted, will spiritually struggle in finding their place in the universe. And remember - you could always use it to make propaganda, in the worst case.

- **Humanities (?)** assuming, of course, your people call themselves humans. Anyway, this is the branch of literature and the other fine arts; but also the study of languages.
- **Foreign Studies** your civilization will meet other uplifted people. When that happens, you'll need scientists able to study and assimilate as much as possible about the other civilization; their language, their habits, their social norms ...
- **Medias and Communication** - either is about news, or getting out your propaganda.

### Development

*That gets the gears running*

Ideally, this would be the department tasked with industries, farms and factories. Your society may work as a state-running machine or like a capitalist utopia, but in either case you'll need some way to ensure that the components for your ships **are** getting built, and **bread** is being baked, somewhere.
So, I'd consider

- **Life support** for food, water and other vital resources (which may extend to breathable gases and whatnot)
- **Industry** with specific focus on the needs of your growing civilization,
- **Automaton** to deal, eventually, with those pesky robots.

Comment: Nice! This covers the most. And better yet, it could be used for modeling other civilizations I have in my story.

Comment: @Vernian42 To be fair, I almost want to write a space civilization too now.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you don't seem to be describing a government at all; you're describing an administration. Most national governments follow a simple pattern.

1) An executive branch, usually ceremonial in nature that becomes the head of state
2) A legislative branch, usually elected (or at least gives that appearance), where the real power is held
3) An administrative branch (including a judiciary), that actually interprets and enacts the edicts of the legislative branch and runs the country in a (hopefully) stable manner

Your government (as you describe it) is not a democracy; it's a theocracy. That is to say, your God has presented himself, uplifted the people, given them a task to do and moved on. The God is your executive branch in that regard and the only doubt that will remain to your race is whether or not he/she plans to come back and check up on progress against the goal. If it was me, I'd assume yes and just get to work, just in case.

As for legislation, well it would appear that your God has set a bunch of rules as part of the uplift procedure. That said, interpretation of those rules and their application in a rapidly changing society (adapting to all this new knowledge) will require a judiciary and possibly a legislature so as to provide a clear tactical direction against the God's strategic statements of intent. So, it may exist, but my guess is that you could almost do that with a judiciary alone, reducing the intercession between the mandates of the God and the people.

Which leaves the administration. Public Services across the world are generally structured according to the needs of the state at a given time; there where very few Departments of the Environment 100 years ago, for instance, but almost every country has had a Customs service for as long as they've existed. For all their newly gained knowledge, you still need food, you actually have a greater need for resources like metal and fuel given your divine brief, and there will still be crime, illness, and a need for educating the young.

So; You'll still have departments for police, schools, hospitals, emergency services, public welfare, etc. In the short term you can probably dispense with the armed forces; your people are now united behind their God in their new mission. Worry about a new military structure when you get into space and start the explorations in earnest. In point of fact, that's the first budget you pillage to make a mega-NASA.

In short, I'd expect that many of the departments you form would be similar to those that are already in place. Your people still have the same needs they had before and at least some of the same problems. The sense of common purpose instilled by your God means that things like customs, immigration and defence are much lower priorities for the short to medium term, until some first contacts start coming along. But, you may end up with some departments you wouldn't have first considered, like a Department of Extraterrestrial Terraforming and Colonisation. Others, like Department of Environment, may be expanded to include the environments of colonial planets. Education will certainly receive a boost to support the massive amount of higher education research that must now be conducted.

The most practical answer is that the only difference between the departments of 'before' and the departments of 'after' will be the differences implied by new priorities set by divine contact.

Comment: Your three parts of government don't match (for example) the US presidential system, which a number of other countries have copied.  I'm also not sure that it matches the UK parliamentary system.  Whether it matches other parliamentary systems is unclear to me.  So I think that "most" is at least an exaggeration.  Can you actually cite a country which is administered by a branch that includes the judiciary rather than by a president or parliament?

Comment: @Brythan, Australia, New Zealand, Canada - pretty much any Commonwealth country, European Monarchies like Denmark, some Asian Monarchies like Thailand. These are just off the top of my head

Comment: The [Canadian Parliament](https://lop.parl.ca/about/parliament/education/ourcountryourparliament/html_booklet/overview-canadian-parliamentary-system-e.html) disagrees with you.  While they agree that the ceremonial monarch is part of the executive, they also put the Prime Minister (not ceremonial) and the administration in the executive.  Their view of the judicial branch is just courts.  The [Australian government](https://www.australia.gov.au/about-government/how-government-works) too.  Is there a particular country with which you are more familiar than these?

Comment: @Brythan I think we're getting bogged down in semantics here. I live in Australia, and the Commonwealth system, while complicated, still sees the Prime Minister as head of the Legislative arm of government. He may be described as part of the executive, but doesn't actually *function* that way. He can't, for example, override the will of the parliament when it comes to a passed law he doesn't like as the recent fracas with off-shore detainees needing medical attention shows. But I know this part of my answer is confusing given how words are used differently in different jurisdictions.

Comment: When I meant uplifted, I meant from a creature/tribal stage directly to the space age. Therefore, there wouldn't be much existing departments, if any.

Comment: Also, I hadn't considered the society to be a theocracy, it's gives me a few other ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

All departments would have sub departments within them but these would be the main groups.

**Armed Services** - Space/air force/army/navy would all be one department. Only humanity would be stupid enough to have separate departments for the groups essentially doing the same job.

**Research** - All the sciences would be here

**Exploration** - This department would map out the galaxy and send out automated drones to search for signs of life and/or interesting planets and resources.

**Governance** - This branch handles and oversees the direction of the executive and distribution of resources, the legal system and general bureaucracy.

**Support** - This department handles the production of resources such as mining, farming and manufacturing. It's the largest group. Also handles health and education.

Comment: Exactly my point about the military deparments. Maybe OP wanted to underline the militaristic nature of his society, but assuming the uplifting gave this people some common sense, there's no point having more departments.

Answer (score 1):

If these species are given only technological knowledge, without any history and political science, they would have to go through a period of chaos before settling on a government style and structure.

At first, they don't have any organization larger than a tribe, and while their knowledge would tell them that they need to combine their efforts in order to build a civilization, they would have no idea how to do that.

Ideally, they would elect a leader who would assign different type of work to different tribes. Those tribes will get specialized in things like agriculture, mining, metallurgy, construction, transportation and scientific research. Military occupation would naturally be reserved for leader's own tribe.

Realistically, tribes would engage in all-out civil war with each other. There would be little time to do actual technological development. A tribe armed with composite bows would wipe out (or enslave) the other tribe which chose a path to make iron tools. Only after some time (and many deaths) one tribe would become victorious and settle on a government type.

Comment: You make a fair point but I doubt this would happen because of the divine nature of the uplifting. As others pointed out, they would likely be united under a common belief. Unless several sects are created based on the word of the god... Hmm..

Comment: @Vernian42 People might be united behind their religion, but they won't be united behind their leaders (unless the god fixes that too). I can imagine bloody wars just because different factions interpret scriptures differently.